# Strange behavior of confirm dialog in gvim

Tags: vim

I have this in my vimrc

```
sil! call neobundle#rc( expand('~/.vim/bundle/') )
if !exists(":NeoBundle")
    let choice = confirm('Run bundle setup ?',"&Yes\n&No", 1)
    if choice == 1 | call Setup_vim() | en
el
    call Load_bundles()
en
```

This works nice in terminal but gvim simply ignores the line and continues as if I clicked Yes in the dialog ?!

This happens only on startup, If I call the function containing this code everything works normally. I guess I could solve this problem using `au` commands but I wanted to know what is the problem here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your vimrc file is read early in the startup process; GUI initialization is much later.  (To be specific, these are steps 3 and 8 under `:help startup`.)

You explicitly set a default value of 1, so it is not surprising that the first alternative is used.

As you say, you can fix it by using a `VimEnter` autocommand.  I tested

```
augroup Foo
  au VimEnter * let choice = confirm('Run bundle setup ?',"&Yes\n&No", 1)
augroup END
```

and it worked as expected.  For real use, I would wrap your lines in a function to keep the autocommand simple.

```
:help startup
:help confirm()
:help :au
:help VimEnter
```